# Can I edit PDF995's pdf995.ini file to enforce colour printing?

Tags: printer, default

I run a program that prints thousands of pages that I need as colour PDF files. I'm using PDF995 as the default printer to create the PDFs. I've checked that PDF995's printing preferences stipulate colour printing, but each PDF is saved in black and white *unless* I adjust it before printing a single file. I've modified pdf995.ini successfully before. **Which line of code would I use to force colour printing?**

Attempts / research: I've experimented and scoured the internet for answers, both unsuccessfully.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi, I believe you posted in the wrong stackexchange. This one is reserved to elementary Operating System related questions. For Windows specific applications questions, you'll most likely have to contact the creator of that software: http://www.pdf995.com/faq.html

Comment: Thanks. I’ve done that (no response). Thought someone here might know a command I can put in a .ini file to specify colour printing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the "Always print in color" option? It is on the "Advanced" tab, under the "Color Options" section.

The pdf995.ini file is used to configure the behavior of the PDF995 printer driver, but it does not have any options specifically related to color printing.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that to no avail. Found an illegitimate solution which was to blitz all trace of PDF995, reinstall it and then choose colour as the default. Seems like there was a default black and white setting buried deep in there that reset every time I launched it.